# How to use substitutions inside inline formatting?

Tags: python, substitution, restructuredtext

I am trying to add a ™ symbol at the end of a bold text. So far niether inline formatting nor the explicit use of `:strong:` role didn't work:

```
.. include:: <isonum.txt>

`something original\ |trade|`:strong:

**something original\ |trade|**
```

I know I can probably define a `|something original (TM)|` as `replace:: unicode:: something original U+02122` but it wouldn't be composable. I'd rather not define one for each use of ™.

Is there a way to get reStructuredText to do the replacement inside inline formatting?

I'm using:

```
Sphinx==1.2.3
Tinkerer==1.4.2
docutils==0.12
```

Comment: I know this post is over 4 years old, but I found this on a search because I've had the same problem.  Is there really no simple way to include substitution variables within mark-ups like boldface?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just paste unicode character? Same way as I pasted it here: ™

Btw, here is what sphinx documentation says:

> Since the easiest way to include special characters like em dashes or
>   copyright signs in reST is to directly write them as Unicode
>   characters, one has to specify an encoding. Sphinx assumes source
>   files to be encoded in UTF-8 by default

Comment: Because using a substitution is more convenient. It's more natural since I can do it with just the keyboard, no copypasta.